# Liquibase & Postgresql: How to migrate varchar column to oid column type

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I am using Liquibase version 4.9 and several databases including Postgres 13.9.

In a createTable statement of the initial database scheme I create a column x of type VARCHAR(4000).

In an upgrade script I try to execute following liquibase script:

```
<modifyDataType columnName="x" newDataType="oid" tableName="y"/>
```

Now I got an error (on non-empty column values):

```
Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type oid: "[]" [Failed SQL: (0) ALTER TABLE public.y ALTER COLUMN x TYPE OID USING (x::OID)]
```

It looks like I have to move all varchar values first to pg_largeobject and link them afterwards. But how to achieve that in an easy way? I don't want to export all values to the disk and import them. Are there any other more convenient functions?

Thanks, Rokko

Comment: Why would you want to use `oid`? Are you planning to store text values larger than 1GB? If not then migrate to `text`

Comment: We are doing that because oid is the default JPA/Hibernate field type for that. We are using @Lob on a String field and it works for Oracle, MsSQL, H2. Postgres is an exception.

Comment: Yeah, that's a hibernate bug. `@Lob` should map to `text` not to "oid" in Postgres. I can't believe they are still trying to use those dreaded large objects

Comment: Ok, thank you. I see here the description of the bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14211 and a possible workaround. In the migration guide https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.6/migration-guide.adoc#changes-to-the-ddl-type-for-clob-in-postgresql81dialect-and-its-subclasses the second update script did what I wanted. But I will think of going to text column type. Thank you!